# __glewX* Undefined Symbols in XQuartz Build

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, linker, glew

​I am trying to compile an X11 application on Mac OS X using XQuartz (i.e. XQuartz provides an X11 implementation, so the code should compile directly).

The X11 code, however, is sophisticated enough to require OpenGL extensions through GLEW.  This almost works, but a few symbols remain undefined.  Here's the relevant, cleaned-up output of the verbose link:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" [flags] -o [out] [lib-dirs] [obj-file] [CustomLib2 CustomLib1] -lX11.6 -lGLEW -lGLEW.1.10 -lc++ -lstdc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___glewXChooseFBConfig", referenced from: [place in CustomLib2]
  "___glewXCreateContextAttribsARB", referenced from: [place in CustomLib2]
  "___glewXSwapIntervalEXT", referenced from: [place in CustomLib2]
```

I checked the libraries, and they don't have any `__glewX*` symbols (though they have lots of `__glew*` symbols), despite [this](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/compat_reports/root/5.23.04_to_5.24.00/abi_compat_report.html) suggesting they should be there. I.e., these commands both come up empty:

```
nm /usr/lib/libGLEW.a | grep __glewX
nm /usr/lib/libGLEW.1.10.0.dylib | grep __glewX
```

**My question: where are the** `__glewX*` **symbols located?**

<sub>N.B. I am not using XCode or CMake.  This is a simple makefile build.</sub>

Comment: The X server that ships with OS X will limit you to OpenGL 2.1, GLEW cannot fix that particular issue. But if you are okay with that, you're going to need to build GLEW targeting GLX instead of the native CGL API that you usually use on OS X.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman see also my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829330/glew-apple-glx-causes-linking-error-when-building-glew?lq=1), posted just a few minutes before your comment.