# GLEW_APPLE_GLX Causes Linking Error When Building GLEW

Tags: opengl, linker, x11, glew

I grepped inside GLEW while trying to solve my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813935/glewx-undefined-symbols-in-xquartz-build), concerning missing `__glewX*` symbols for Mac, and found that they are guarded by `GLEW_APPLE_GLX`.

When I attempt to build GLEW from source with that flag defined, I get undefined symbols (stuff like `_glXGetClientString`).  Linking against X11 (`-lX11`) doesn't help.

Question: assuming defining `GLEW_APPLE_GLX` does indeed make sense, how can I fix the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building an application that uses the X Server (XQuartz) instead of using CGL, you also need to add `-lGL`.

Ordinarily when building GL software on OS X you use ***OpenGL.framework*** (`-framework OpenGL`) and that gets you OpenGL and CGL/AGL functions but leaves out GLX.

You should also ditch any includes to things like `<OpenGL/gl.h>` and use `<GL/gl.h>` instead, as that will point to `/usr/X11R6/include/GL/...` instead of the OpenGL framework headers.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  And, tweaking the makefile with `-lGL` fixes the problem.  Specifically, I added `-DGLEW_APPLE_GLX` to `CFLAGS` and `-L/usr/x11R6/lib/ -lX11.6 -lGL.1` to `LIB.LDFLAGS` (which fixed the library builds, though not `glewinfo`).  Also note, one shouldn't be using the `*/gl.h` includes anyway; GLEW is meant to replace them.

Comment: Note: even though the program _compiles_, I still [get issues at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830635/dyld-missing-glx-from-libx11).