# dyld Missing glX* from libX11

Tags: opengl, dyld, glx, xquartz

​While attempting to run `[executable]`, a program I wrote under Linux and am attempting to test under XQuartz on OSX, I get:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _glXChooseVisual
  Referenced from: [executable]
  Expected in: /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
[...]
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

The only precedent I could find was [this](https://sft.its.cern.ch/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/ROOT-5460/ROOT-5460.html), which wasn't resolved.  My program uses GLEW as set up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829330/glew-apple-glx-causes-linking-error-when-building-glew).  Clearly, `glXChooseVisual` isn't being found, but I would *expect* it in `libX11`, so . . . what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glXChooseVisual is located in libGL not in libX11